# How to disable anonymous access to MongoDB 3.0.x in linux

Tags: mongodb, authentication, centos, disabled-control

we are using centos 7 , mongodb 3.0.8 
Im trying to disable anonymous access to mongodb.
Place auth = true in /etc/mongod.conf disabling anonymous access in version 2.x
but in version 3 when i place the same , the server it self not starting

When i hard search , i found in the mongo docs that in version 3.x
security.authorization should be placed in /etc/mongod.conf

Could any one please help me how to place security.authorization in config file.

Answer (score 4):

add the following to the mongod.conf file:

```
security:
  authorization: enabled
```

Comment: still can access without password.